# ESP32-s2 Wroom. Are the SDMMC pins same as in ESP32 (not S2)

Tags: sd, esp32, pinout

The documentation is not very clear.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/sdmmc_host.html

[image]

Are pins the same in the S2 variant?

Comment: Check your title. Did you mean ESP32-S2 instead of ESP32-32? Did you check the datasheets to see if the pins are the same?